# #2006 - MySQL server has gone away using xampp and mysql

Tags: mysql, database, import, xampp

I want to import the `ibd` files of a table because my `ibdata1` has gone, so I'm manually importing the tables to new database, some tables work properly, but the others won't.

I've tried to change the maximum time out, the maximum file and other things, but these dont work.

my.ini code:

```
    # Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
    #bdb_cache_size = 4M
    #bdb_max_lock = 10000
    
    # Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
    #skip-innodb
    innodb_data_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
    innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
    innodb_log_group_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
    #innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
    ## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
    ## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048M
    ## Set .._log_file_size to 55 % of buffer pool size
    innodb_log_file_size=128M
    innodb_log_buffer_size=128M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout=5000
            
    character-set-server=utf8mb4
    collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
    [mysqldump]
    max_allowed_packet=1048576M
    
    [mysql]
    # Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
    #safe-updates
    
    [isamchk]
    key_buffer=1024M
    sort_buffer_size=256M
    read_buffer=8M
    write_buffer=16M
    
    [myisamchk]
    key_buffer=1024M
    sort_buffer_size=256M
    read_buffer=8M
    write_buffer=8M
    
    [mysqlhotcopy]
    interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost the ibdata1 then you have basically lost the heart of the system. Ibdata1 maintains the data dictionary for innodb and also contains the metadata about each table however table ibd file contains only the data/index of the table. You cannot import an ibd file just like that without doing a proper export of it using below command which would give you table_name.{ibd,cfg} files which you would need to import. If you don't have a working latest backup restoring all the tables would be impossible from here.

```
FLUSH TABLES t1 FOR EXPORT;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html